# Refresh activity without any animation

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to refresh an activity which will change a textview value after every 5 second without any animation.i searched in stackoverflow also but can't get proper solution.please help

Comment: Please add code you have already done for the matter. Have you done code for the time interval..?

Comment: Instead of refreshing activity refresh the method and textview value

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this answers your question but would it work if set the text in the textView every 5 seconds? Using the txtView.setText("your text"); and then have a delay in between each time you set it? I hope this works and makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `Handler`. Here's how :

```
private boolean started = false;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {        
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textview.setText("####"); // <- text to be updated every 5 sec
                        if(started) {
                            start();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
};

public void stop() {
    started = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public void start() {
    started = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);        
}
```